# Get 'N' number of records in marklogic

Tags: marklogic

I have about **53,00,000** document in my MarkLogic server database, and each document contains one record.
Please tell me how can I get N number of records in MarkLogic.

I do not want to use the search API.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to get the first N documents in the database, regardless of what they are, you could do this:

```
(/node())[1 to $n]
```

That assumes you have defined a variable $n. If you want to use some search criteria, you could do something like this instead:

```
cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:do-some-search-here())[1 to $n]
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want a count of the documents?

```
xdmp:estimate(doc())
```

See http://community.marklogic.com/try/ninja/index for a tutorial that will walk you thru some of this.

Answer (score 1):

Analogous to the answer of Dave Cassel, you can also use:

```
doc()[$start to $end]
```

or even better:

```
collection()[$start to $end]
```

or for full XQuery compliance:

```
collection()[position() = ($start to $end)]
```

HTH

Comment: Also worth mentioning: [`fn:subsequence()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/fn:subsequence): `fn:subsequence(collection(), $start, $end)`